# Handling MySQL deadlock in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

Perhaps this is due to a gap in my understanding, but I've been trying to find a solution to the Deadlock issue in MySQL for the past few days. Despite my efforts, I'm still encountering a deadlock. I attempted to manage it using a try-catch block (\Exception $e), but the deadlock error isn't being caught. Does anyone have an alternative method to catch a MySQL deadlock error?

My objective in catching deadlock errors is to implement a retry mechanism whenever a deadlock occurs.

I'm using this CodeIgniter model, but even when a deadlock occurs, the log_message doesn't log anything.

```
public function updateUserBalance($userid, $balance)
{
    try {
        return $this->db->table($this->user)
            ->set('balance', "balance+{$balance}", false)
            ->where('id', $userid)
            ->update();
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // Handle deadlock error
        log_message('error', 'Deadlock occurred: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Any answer is very valuable to me. Thank You

Comment: What is the _exact_ error you're experiencing?

Comment: @ADyson I can't avoid transactions altogether causing the error "mysqli_sql_exception: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction".

Comment: Ok. But please [edit] your question to include the error message (and any other important information when you have it) - don't bury such info down in these comments. It needs to all be in your question so everything's clear and easily visible to readers. See also [ask]. Thanks :-)

Comment: I didn't include the problem because my question was how to catch the error when a deadlock occurs on mysql. because the code I listed cannot handle deadlock errors.

Comment: Ok. But we have to ensure we understand precisely what error message we're dealing with, in order to be sure the correct solution is given. Never ever truncate, paraphrase or otherwise alter error messages when reporting them - it simply introduces unncessary ambiguity. Copy and paste the exact full error message into your question, then everyone can be 100% sure they are talking about the same thing that you are. "deadlock error" might conceivably cover more than one particular case, for example. Doing that simple task is faster than commenting to try to justify why you didn't! :-)